# pip install problems Mac OS X Sierra error

Tags: python, macos

error while trying to install pyaudio pasted below. Any advice on how to proceed? Many thanks,

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.dylib
    running install_lib
    copying build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_portaudio.so -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_portaudio.so'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/x1/xnwzchk163v1r7jy4fz6y3yh0000gn/T/pip-build-l3A43i/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x1/xnwzchk163v1r7jy4fz6y3yh0000gn/T/pip-7eoPR0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x1/xnwzchk163v1r7jy4fz6y3yh0000gn/T/pip-build-l3A43i/pyaudio/
```

Comment: *file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386):* -- Your CPU architecture is incorrect for the library you want

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the final problem he is probably asking about. The permission denied error indicates you are not running ``pip`` with ``sudo``. As a result you will not have permission to install packages in the ``site-packages`` for the system Python version.

Comment: The first issue was a warning and it safely ignored the incompatible library. The second issue means the user didn't have the privilege to write to system directory. The solution is to let the administrators do this kind of tasks.

Comment: Users who commonly run into this issues normally have their own sandboxed `python` such as `anaconda` or `miniconda`. I will not recommend running the installation using `sudo` until the OP is certain that the installation is being run on the correct location.

Comment: Thanks for responses. I am system admin, sole user on MacBook, OSX Sierra. Any ideas how I might repair permissions?

Comment: alvits, thanks, how do I determine where the installation is being run?

Comment: @Harley_Looyah Use the @ symbol to notify a specific user that you targeted him/her in an comment.

Comment: @alvits thanks for notes. I don't have anaconda or miniconda. Python is installed in main library, not usr/Library. Others have suggest virtualenv better approach than sudo. Tried installing virtualenv but ran into similar permissions error on install: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'

Comment: @Harley_Looyah - you have 2 options here. First option is somewhat disconcerting. Run your installation using `sudo`. This will effectively modify the system default python distribution and any mistake you make could prove to be catastrophic. Second option is to install `miniconda`. This installs on your home directory. Removing this installation is as simple as removing the directory that you installed it into. Any mistake you make, won't affect the system adversely. You will be affected but you can simply delete the directory.